# Assign a value to a struct value-type

Tags: c#

I want to be able to create a struct, and use it like a normal built-in.
For example, say I decide that the Bool should also have a FileNotFound value (as a silly example!), so I create a struct to include that - what would it take to be able to use it as a normal struct in code (ie. assign to it), as in 
  bool b = true;  or
  b = FileNotFound;

The Bool is a struct, right? And you can do it with the other built-ins:
int i = 32; or
byte b = 123;

I want to do my own!
Anyone got any ideas...?

Cheers - Richard

Comment: +1 to counter unfair downvote... that's a perfectly legitimate question

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an `enum`: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

`enum`'s are sets of values that can be used as types.

So you can do:

```
enum MyBool {True=1, False, FileNotFound};
MyBool b = MyBool.FileNotFound;
```

If you want methods, use a `struct` and an `enum`: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
public struct MyBool
{
   internal enum Values {True=1, False, FileNotFound};
   Values value;

   public MyBool(Values v) 
   {
      value = v; 
   }
}
MyBool b = new MyBool(MyBool.Values.FileNotFound);
```

The `Values` of the `struct` will only be available to it when declaring a new instance (or if you make any other methods that use it).

You probably want to initialize the `value` variable in the struct to something, because the constructor for the `struct` can still be called without a value.

Comment: Yes.  But you forgot FileNotFound.

Comment: But I want a (value) type - And for it to have methods etc.

Comment: This won't compile, the constructor can't be public if the enum is internal. Otherwise, that's a good answer, +1 ;)

Comment: works for me....  if it doesnt, you can make the enum public, but that exposes it to outside use from the struct

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, in general, do this sort of thing in C#.

Comment: How come you can with the built-ins?
Isn't the framework suposed to be written in c#?

Never mind - It was just an idea :-)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: No, enums are not literal struct values. Obviously you can set up a system that will simulate this, but you cannot make your own literals like you can in C++0x or other languages.

Comment: Well, sure, you can't create your own literals... but you can do everything else